# Waiting for batch process to finish before continuing with the rest of the codes in .java file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have this java file, where I need to invoke a batch file from,
for this, I use the following line

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+ "D:\\Builds\\automation\\INSTALLER\\SOURCE\\A.bat");
```

This runs fine, the bat file is invoked in command prompt.
A.bat also has a few lines where 2 other bat files are called. You can consider them as B.bat & C.bat

After all these Batch files are run, there is a output.log file that is generated & has information if the process was "successful" or there were "errors". So based on the words in the log, I will need to either print "SUCCESS" or "ERROR".

Now, my problem is, I used

```
proc.waitFor();
```

so that the java file wait for the Process to finish before the remaining codes are run.
This just does not happen. Even before B.bat is run, "SUCCESS" gets printed.

Is there a way I could edit the batch file according to my needs or edit the java file to wait till the process completes?

Comment: Is A.bat waiting for B.bat and C.bat to finish? How do you start B and C from A? Post some code of A, plz.

Comment: Within `A.bat`, are you invoking `B.bat` and `C.bat` using `call`?  Using `call` will pause `A.bat` while the others execute, and return the thread of execution back to `A.bat` when the others are complete.  Also, you might consider using exit codes to determine success / fail.  `exit /b 0` for success, or `exit /b 1` for fail, and interpret it using `proc.exitValue()`.

Comment: I dont think `A.bat` is waiting. I'm using `CALL` to invoke `B.bat` & `C.bat`

Comment: Could this be the problem? Even if Java is waiting for A it won't wait for B and C. Try to run B and C using `start /wait B.bat`and `start /wait C.bat`.

Comment: right, so i'm guess i should use the same start /wait which i call A.bat as well? i'm going to try this

Comment: I think you don't need `start /wait` for A because you already make your program wait for it with `proc.waitFor();`.

Comment: i tried with /wait & without /wait. it seems to wait to execute other lines in java only if I use /wait

`Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait A.bat", null, new File("D:\\Builds\\automation\\INSTALLER\\SOURCE"));`

`proc.waitFor();`

it wont wait insipte of forWait() & continues to run remaining lines